# Multithreaded code: vector<bool> iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading

The following code is intended to return the smallest non-negative integer that is not already in use.  It is called from multiple threads.  If style looks a bit odd, it's because this class is intended to live in a header-only library.

```
class Unique
{
public:
    static unsigned int getIndex()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(get().mutex);
        unsigned int index = 0;
        while (index < get().valueInUse.size() && get().valueInUse[index])
            index++;
        if (index == get().valueInUse.size()) get().valueInUse.push_back(true);
        get().valueInUse[index] = true;
        return index;
    }
    static void releaseIndex(unsigned int index)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(get().mutex);
        get().valueInUse[index] = false;
    }
private:
    static Unique &get()
    {
        static Unique s;
        return s;
    }
    boost::mutex mutex;
    std::vector<bool> valueInUse;
};
```

A debug-time problem occasionally occurs with this code:

```
vector<bool> iterators incompatible
```

Stack trace shows the problem happening at the `push_back()` - `index` is zero.  The STL implementation seems to think it is inserting at the `end()` of another instance of `vector<bool>`.  Using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Any ideas?  This code is thread-safe, isn't it?

Comment: Instead of a `vector<bool>` you can use `std::bitset`(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/).

Comment: @yasouser you need to know the size of the `bitset` at compile time though.

Comment: Also see the section titled "Vector specialization: vector<bool>" in this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/. It specifically talks about references to elements in the `vector<bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `get` function certainly isn't thread-safe unless you guarantee that it's called once before any threads are created. And since you use the `get` call to get the mutex to protect the rest of the code, you could definitely get some unexpected results there.

`std::vector<bool>` is explicitly specialized to use one bit per bool so that does change iteration results (it uses a proxy object I believe). Have you tried using `deque` instead of `vector` just as a test?

Comment: Also consider [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).